# DISTINCT ON в Zend Framework

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework

В `Zend Framework` есть метод `distinct()`, который выполняет `DISTINCT` в `sql`, а есть метод для `DISTINCT ON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html) не является частью стандарта SQL, и по этому, не смотря на то, что PostgreSql поддерживает этот метод, Zend Framework не поддерживает его.

Comment: $select->distinct так добавляется DISTINCT, можно как то туда ручками вписать DISTINCT ON?не метод вызвать, а строку вставить?

Comment: На сколько мне известно, сделать то что вы хотите можно только путем расширения адаптера.

Comment: т.е. залезть в зенд и прописать новый нужный мне метод?

Comment: @hik нет, не нужно лезть в зенд, просто создайте свое расширение имеющегося адаптера и допилите так как вам нужно. Тут можете почитать о рассмотрении аналогичного вопроса: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998382/how-to-build-a-select-using-zend-with-a-distinct-specific-column